# how can i update entity synchonous in spring jpa

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

i have an issue :
i have a product entity which have 2 columns id and quantity
_so i have 2 api

- one for update this will update product entity quantity (quantity = quantity - 1)
- one for update this will update product entity quantity (quantity = quantity + 1)
  the issue is then I call 2 api in the same time, this result not my expect here is my diagram
  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Je6Xi.png)

can anyone help my thank you

Comment: You are calling both Apis at the same time ?? have you tried using Pessimistic Locking(Pessimistic_write_lock) in spring jpa ?

Comment: well, i will research it, thank you for your answer

Answer (score 1):

Well for your particular scenario there is a concept called locking. And there is two type of locking

1. Optimistic
2. Pessimistic

The idea is when one transaction is updating a row of a db table, you should not allow another transaction to update that row util the previous one is committed.

In application there are several ways to achieve this type of locking. We can describe this concurrent updating process as a **Collision**. In a system where a collision is not going to happen very frequently you can use the optimisting locking approach.

In optimistic approach you keep a `version` number in your row. When you perform an update you increase the version by 1. Let's analyse your scenario now and call your two service **I** (increase) and **D** (decrease). You have a product row **P** in your database table where `quantity = 3`, `version = 0`. When `I` and `D` is called for both of them when they fetch `P` from database the state of `P` is as below

> quantity = 3, version = 0

Now `D` executes first and decrease and save `P`
Your update query should be like below

```
 UPDATE Product p set p.quantity = :newQuantity
, p.version = p.version + 1 where p.version = :oldVersion and p.id = :id
```

For case of `D` value of `newQuantity = 2` `(oldQty - 1)` and value of `oldVersion = 0` (we fetched it at the beginning)

Now the current state of `P` is like below

> quantity = 2, version = 1

Now when `I` tries to execute you should generate the same update query but for this case value of `newQuantity = 4` `(oldQty +1)` and value of `oldVersion = 0` (we fetched it at the beginning).

If you put these value to the update query your row won't be updated as it the version checking part will be false. From this you can then throw any locking exception to notify your client that the request could not be completed and can try again. This is basically the core concept of optimistic locking and there is much more efficient ways to handle it with frameworks like `Hibernate`

Here you can notice that we have not denied any of the read requests while updating the row but in the approach of `Pessimistic` locking you deny any read request when another transaction on going. So basically when `D` is on process of decreasing `I` would not be able to read the value and from there you can return to your client saying that the request was not completed. But this approach takes a toll on read heavy tables in exchange of tight data integrity.